# Ramda - get array of objects using ids from other array

Tags: ramda.js

I have two sets of data and I would like to use the first one to get an array of objects from the second one. I tried to deal with it by myself but I am missing few steps.

Here is set of ids to use:

```js
const idSet = {
  "41": {
    "id": "41"
  },
  "42": {
    "id": "42"
  },
  "43": {
    "id": "43"
  }
}
```

And here is second set:

```js
const nodes = {
  "3": {
    "nodeCommentId": 3,
    "nodeId": 43,
  },
  "4": {
    "nodeCommentId": 4,
    "nodeId": 41
  },
  "6": {
    "nodeCommentId": 6,
    "nodeId": 42
  },
  "7": {
    "nodeCommentId": 7,
    "nodeId": 44
  },
}
```

I need to search by `id` and `nodeId` so I tried to use something like this to get only ids from first set:

```js
const ids = R.compose(
  R.values(),
  R.pluck('id')
)(idSet)
```

I also came up with something like: `R.filter(R.compose(R.flip(R.contains)(ids), R.prop('nodeId')), nodes);`

But then I have `nodeId` which is a number and not a string plus I need an array of objects without keys.

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    nodeCommentId: 3,
    nodeId: 43
  },
  {
    nodeCommentId: 4,
    nodeId: 41
  },
  {
    nodeCommentId: 6,
    nodeId: 42
  }
]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output you're looking for?

Comment: You can convert `ids` to numerics with `R.map(Number)`. Then your later filtering works: https://jsbin.com/nofatayesi/edit?js,console

Comment: @ScottSauyet I am trying to get an array with objects 41, 42, 43 inside

Comment: I doubt you just mean `[41, 42, 43]`, so could you [edit] the post to include the desired output?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Done. Now it should be clear.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you. It is almost what I need. Do you know how to get rid of object keys and leave the array which I added to the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably too ugly to use, but it might be a start at a nice solution:

```js
const nodesById = (idSet) => {
  const ids = map (Number, pluck ('id') (values (idSet)))
  return pipe (values, filter (pipe (prop('nodeId'), contains(__, ids))))
}

const idSet = {41: {id: "41"}, 42: {id: "42"}, 43: {id: "43"}}
const nodes = {3: {nodeCommentId: 3, nodeId: 43, }, 4: {nodeCommentId: 4, nodeId: 41}, 6: {nodeCommentId: 6, nodeId: 42}, 7: {nodeCommentId: 7, nodeId: 44}}

console .log (
  nodesById (idSet) (nodes)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {map, pluck, values, pipe, filter, prop, contains, __} = R </script>
```

I'm sure that with a little work, we could make this entirely point-free, but I doubt that  will help readability.

Answer (score 1):

Transform the `idSet` to an array of numbers, and then user R.innerJoin to get the items with the matching `nodeId`:

```js
const { pipe, values, pluck, map, innerJoin, __, curry } = R

const getIds = pipe(values, pluck('id'), map(Number))

const getNodesById = curry((idSet, nodes) => 
  pipe(
    values, 
    innerJoin(
      ({ nodeId }, id) => nodeId === id, 
      __,
      getIds(idSet)
    )
  )(nodes)
)

const idSet = {41: {id: "41"}, 42: {id: "42"}, 43: {id: "43"}}
const nodes = {3: {nodeCommentId: 3, nodeId: 43, }, 4: {nodeCommentId: 4, nodeId: 41}, 6: {nodeCommentId: 6, nodeId: 42}, 7: {nodeCommentId: 7, nodeId: 44}}

const result = getNodesById(idSet)(nodes)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```